# Trying to calculate percent saving for mortgage

Tags: python

I'm new to python. Working my way through the MIT OCW 6.001 Intro to Computer Science and Programming in Python. Need to create a script that calculates the portion of income to set aside to afford a mortgage. I need to use the bisection method to find the portion to set aside. When I run my script, I get a bunch of angry text about how my function 'savings' takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given. I don't know what that means. Help please!

Here's the code:

```
"""
Created on Thu Mar 16 12:51:41 2017

@author: [redacted]
"""

num_guesses = int(0)
current_savings = int(0)
annual_salary = input('enter your annual salary:')
r = float(.04)
raise_pct = float (.07)
high = pct_saved = float(1.0)
low = 0 
def savings (): 
    total_savings = 0 
    num_months = 0
    monthly_salary = int(annual_salary)/12
    portion_saved = pct_saved*monthly_salary
    for num_months in range(0,35): 
        num_months += 1
        total_savings += (current_savings*r)/12 + portion_saved
        if (num_months%6) == 0 :
            monthly_salary += monthly_salary*raise_pct
            portion_saved = monthly_salary*pct_saved
        return total_savings
cost = 250000
epsilon = float(.001)
guess = (low + high)/2.0
if savings(high) < cost:
    num_guesses += 1
    print ('You cannot afford this house.')
while abs(savings(guess))-cost >= epsilon: 
    if savings(guess) < cost: 
        low = guess
    else: 
        high = guess
    guess = (high + low)/2.0
    num_guesses += 1
print ('Number of guesses:', num_guesses)
print ('Savings percent is near:', pct_saved)
```

Comment: I suggest you play with functions in the interpreter to get to grips with them.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is exactly correct: you defined `savings` to take no arguments, but call it with an argument (either `high` or `guess`).

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because the savings function doesn't take any arguments. Here's how functions work:

```
# no arguments
def function():
    return 1

print function() # prints 1

# one argument
def function2(arg):
    return arg

a = 2
print function2(a) # prints 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if savings(high) < cost:
num_guesses += 1
print ('You cannot afford this house.')
```

This is the where your error is coming from. Based on this particular code snippet, you are calling the `function` savings and giving it one variable.

However, you clearly define savings to take no arguments.

```
def savings ():
# your other code down here.
```

To fix this, you need to do something along the lines of

```
def savings(amountOfSavings):
# your other code down here
```

I also want to point out that there is no space between the function name and the parenthesis that contain the arguments.

I also recommend playing with the interpreter so you understand how functions work and are called. To do this, run python on the command line via. `python` and do simple things like `add(2, 2)`. If the command line spits on an error, you probably need to put Python in the command line (there are many YouTube videos on how to do this).

After that you can run your script in interactive mode to play around with your functions. To do this, you do `python -i yourScriptName.py`.